# Python Update values of dict with other mutual values in dict

Tags: python

I am trying to find mutual numbers not in current values but key is in other values
I have a dict where I need to replace the current values with values where the key is in another key's values. So my dict in is like this:

```
dict_in =  {'1': [3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12], 
            '4': [2, 5, 7, 8, 9], 
            '2': [3, 4, 7, 6, 13], 
            '12': [1, 7, 5, 9], 
            '3': [9, 11, 10, 1, 2, 13], 
            '10': [1, 3, 6, 11], 
            '5': [4, 1, 7, 11, 12], 
            '13': [2, 3], 
            '8': [1, 6, 4, 11], 
            '7': [5, 2, 4, 9, 12], 
            '11': [3, 5, 10, 8], 
            '9': [12, 1, 3, 6, 4, 7]}
```

what I am expecting is something like this
1: [7, 11, 10, 2, 13, 6, 11, 4, 7, 11, 12, 6, 4, 11, 12, 6, 4, 7],  since 1 is in the values of 12,3,10,5,8 and 9 so I want all the values for those keys to now be the values of 1 instead of [3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12]. Hopefully I haven't confused anyone too much.

My code is here:

```
dict_out = {}
for key in dict_in: 
   for k,v in dict_in.items():     
       for y in v:  
          if int(key) in v and y != int(key):
              dict_out.setdefault(int(key), []).append(y)
```

and what I am getting is this for the number 1:

```
1: [7, 5, 9, 9, 11, 10, 2, 13, 3, 6, 11, 4, 7, 11, 12, 6, 4, 11, 12, 3, 6, 4, 7]
```

so it should not contain 3,5,9 or 12.

So I want all values from another set of values if the key of those values is that other set of values but I do not want my current values for the key. Someplace I am not checking the current values against the 'potential' values.

Comment: I'm curious...is there some actual problem that your algorithm solves...something real world, or is this a homework assignment or something like that?

Comment: It is supposed to be like social networks finding mutual connections. Person A know Person B and Person C but not person so Person A might know Person D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this might not be the most optimised solution but it will be good for your code:

```
dict_in =  {'1': [3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12], 
            '4': [2, 5, 7, 8, 9], 
            '2': [3, 4, 7, 6, 13], 
            '12': [1, 7, 5, 9], 
            '3': [9, 11, 10, 1, 2, 13], 
            '10': [1, 3, 6, 11], 
            '5': [4, 1, 7, 11, 12], 
            '13': [2, 3], 
            '8': [1, 6, 4, 11], 
            '7': [5, 2, 4, 9, 12], 
            '11': [3, 5, 10, 8], 
            '9': [12, 1, 3, 6, 4, 7]}

dict_out = {}
for key in dict_in: 
   for k,v in dict_in.items():     
       for y in v:  
          if (int(key) in v) and (y != int(key)) and (y not in dict_in[key]):
              dict_out.setdefault(int(key), []).append(y)

print(dict_out)
```

I have added another conditional which should make it work :)